# ASP.NET - how do you change the way a JSON gets serialized?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I'm using ASP.NET to return a Json file with the following query:

```
public ActionResult getTransactionTotals(int itemID)
    {
        DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

        var query = from trans in db.Transactions
                    // Linq query removed for brevity
                        into selection
                        select new TransactionAmount
                        {
                            name = selection.Key,
                            amount = selection.Select(t => t.TransactionId).Distinct().Count()
                        };

        return Json(query.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here's the object that gets created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OhYeah
{
public class TransactionAmount
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
}
}
```

Which returns a JSON in this form:

```
[{"name":"billy", "amount":5}, {"name":"timmy", "amount":18}]
```

Now, I want to edit either the Linq query or the Json serializer to output a Json like this:

```
[{"billy":5, "timmy":18}]
```

Notice the second Json is a single item, where the "name" key is now the value of "name" in the first Json. The "name" and "amount" keys are discarded. The "name" value is always unique, there can be no two billy's or timmy's, so that does not have to be taken into account.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try thus

```
public ActionResult getTransactionTotals(int itemID)
    {
        DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

        var query = (from trans in db.Transactions
                    // Linq query removed for brevity
                        into selection
                        select new TransactionAmount
                        {
                            name = selection.Key,
                            amount = selection.Select(t => t.TransactionId).Distinct().Count()
                        }).ToDictionary(k => k.name, v => v.amount);



        return Json(query,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

put your query in a dictionary after serializes

Comment: My TransactionAmount does not have a ToDictionary method. TransactionAmount is a very basic class, that only holds a String and an int. It does not extend any other classes that might contain ToDictionary. How would I add ToDictionary functionality to a class?

Comment: before ToList and after ToDictionary

Comment: You might have to wrap the query in `()` before you call call `.ToList()` or `ToDictionary()`; so `var query = (from trans......select new{...}).ToDictionary()`

Comment: Thanks for your help Fabio and C Sharper! The final solution is slightly different, mind if I edit your post to what worked for me?

Comment: (from trans......select new{...}).ToDictionary() is also right , sorry for my mistakes